# Bootstrap inline input group - label, input-box and button

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to get the cleanest HTML markup, not reliant on additional custom CSS ("bootstrap out the box") to achieve something similar to this demo I created on bootply - http://www.bootply.com/1Uy4UROiEz

The only thing wrong with the demo above is I want the go button to be attached to the the input box as shown in this other demo demo - http://www.bootply.com/yEhbA5gkdm

The problem is that I need the button and input bow to have its own size (col-md-??) so that the button can be wider.

Can anybody give me some good code that can accomplish this please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can modify the width of the go button by attaching a CSS class with width set to whatever value you want the button width to be. You can find a modified version of your example here: http://www.bootply.com/UMZt0xqvrD#.

**Edit:**
When using form control it seems that you will have to specify one element using the bootstrap predefined widths and define another yourself. I modified the first example here http://www.bootply.com/kxMFprsSZN

Comment: Thanks for your answer, please try and apply this to the first bootply link above - http://www.bootply.com/1Uy4UROiEz You will see my problem

Comment: When using form control it seems that you will have to specify one element using the bootstrap predefined widths and define another yourself. I modified the first example here http://www.bootply.com/kxMFprsSZN